# how to only rate limit 1 endpoint in nest.js

Tags: graphql, nestjs

does including the module and useGuard this in one place allow me to ONLY rate limit this one service? if not what's the best way to rate limit a single endpoint?

```
ThrottlerModule.forRoot(),

@UseGuards(ThrottlerGuard)
@Throttle(10, 60)
@Query()
async myQuery() {
  return await this
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right according to the documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have above is fine. That's how guards work, if you apply it to a single route, it'll only effect that route.